# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<Map<String, dynamic>>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, exception, casting, iterable, unhandled

I am trying to solve this issue that come up after every time I pull down to refresh.
The issue message "Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<Map<String, dynamic>>' in type cast".
As you can see in the pictures uploaded the error message in terminal and the function code.
How can I solve it?

[image]

[image]

Code here

````
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    apiNewsPage.getNewsArticles().then((res) {
      setState(() {
        articles = res!;
        _newsArticles.addAll(articles.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>());
      });
    });
  }

  Future<void> refreshList() async {
    List? articles = await apiNewsPage.getNewsArticles(refresh: true);
    setState(() {
      _newsArticles.clear();
      _newsArticles.addAll(articles! as Iterable<Map<String, dynamic>>);
    });
  } ```
````

Comment: try `_newsArticles.addAll(articles.cast<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>());`

Comment: It gives me error: The argument type 'List<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<Map<String, dynamic>>'.

Comment: You have to know that the `List` are an object, the `Map` other object, the `List<Map<K,V>>` other object, and `Itareable<T>` other object. Although all them have things in common are different objects. Saying that you must know what the Future "getNewsArticles()" comes from. Knowing that you can convert by some method that object provide or iterate one by one elements in order to add to _newsArticles. Last but not least, Doesn't share images as code

Comment: ```_newsArticles.addAll(articles?.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>() ?? []);```
or simply
```_newsArticles.addAll(articles?.cast() ?? []);```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is type mismatch with `List<dynamic>`, so you have to cast every item in the list.

Try with following code

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    apiNewsPage.getNewsArticles().then((res) {
      setState(() {
        articles = res!;
        _newsArticles.addAll(articles.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>());
      });
    });
  }

  Future<void> refreshList() async {
    List? articles = await apiNewsPage.getNewsArticles(refresh: true);
    setState(() {
      _newsArticles.clear();
      _newsArticles.addAll(articles!.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();//Here is a change
    });
  }
```